# oracle insert o into timestamp column

Tags: sql, oracle, etl, informatica-powercenter, flat-file

I am having a csv file which contains 0 in timestamp column in source , when it is being inserted into oracle through informatica it is populated as NULL values. I am not sure whether this is correct . whether it should be 0 or NULL or any other value. Could anyone confirm on this.

Comment: `0` doesn't represent a timestamp, what would you suggest it does other than giving `NULL`? An error is all I can imagine

Comment: And exactly what "time"  (actually, date/time) would you expect the simple numeric value of zero to represent?

Comment: @EdStevens - when it all started :) - big bang time may be. @abirami - Jokes apart, this is expected behavior from informatica. You can use a logic like this `IIF(col=0, null, col)` to replace 0 with null or you cna use sysdate too or any default date.

Comment: Do you want the year 0 to be 1900, 1970 or the year you were born?

Comment: 0 is - obviously - 1st of Jan, 1970 - the begining of time! :)

Comment: @KoushikRoy - Well, I myself may not be older than dirt, but I'm old enough to have known people who were . . . :-)

Comment: lol :) its being a enjoyable comment thread. So, every software born on 1-January-1970 ?

Comment: Hi, I was about to mention 0 which is an integer, it is date/time when it is getting loaded to informatica, and for now it is loaded as NULL. As @KoushikRoy suggested we can specify default time if we want. 

Thank you all for suggestions

Comment: You can default in informatica `IIF(col=0, to_date('01011970','mmddyyyy') , col)` using 1 jan 1970 or any date you want to.

Answer (score 0):

This is the expected behavior, as ORACLE can't store 0 in a timestamp column.